# Why does the vote count of an upvoted comment turn black?

Tags: support, comments, design, voting

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

After retracting:

[image]

Why does the vote count turn black and stay the same when retracting? Is there any rationale behind this?

Moreover, this behavior cannot be observed with higher vote counts:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

After retracting:

[image]

Why is that?

I am using Safari 9.0.3 on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3 in case that's of any value.

---

The examples are taken from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). If the behavior differs on other websites within the Stack Exchange network, notify me, please, and I'll adjust my question accordingly.

Comment: I believe this is related to comment "hotness" (I forgot the official term). Comment score have different color based on their score to indicate it's hotness, which should tell of it's important (or sometimes, interesting). Higher score tends to show more contrast color.